# How to pass a time stamp to a Git tag

Tags: git, github

I'm interested in running this on my git master branch for timestamped releases:

```
tag -a date_time_as_tag_name -m "new release"
git push tags
```

Is there a command that will create the timestamp for me?

Comment: Try the [`date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) command.

Comment: This seems a little odd to me, since annotated tags contain the date. It's like using the current date as a commit message.

Comment: it was a naming convention that I inherited that went something like "release-201101211020" and I couldn't figure out how to run date "+%Y%m%d%H%M"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a unix setup, you can use [date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date). On windows, there's the same named 
[date](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/date.mspx?mfr=true) command.

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your ~/.gitconfig file:

```
git config alias.datetag '!git tag `date "+%Y%m%d%H%M"`'
```

Comment: You can't 'try this in your ~/.gitconfig'. If you want to put that alias into your ~/.gitconfig you have to use: "git config --global alias.datetag '!git tag `date "+%Y%m%d%H%M"`'"

Comment: Thanks everyone, I don't really need to add it to my git config, just was looking for the unix date command. This is giving me what I need: date "+%Y%m%d%H%M"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [jschorr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752432/1352748), to create an annotated tag using the current Date/Time as the name:

```
git tag -a `date “+%d%b%Y%H%M%S”` -m "enter your comment here"
```

Listing with `git tag` we can see something like:

```
23Nov2017115959
```

Comment: Took your example and added this to my development env: ```git tag -a releases/develop/`date "+%d%b%Y%H%M%S"` -m "push to develop environment"
```

works great

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), you will have a more intuitive way to pass a timestamp to a Gti command: for instance, "`git config --expiry-date gc.reflogexpire`" can read "`2.weeks`" from the configuration and report it as a timestamp, just like "`--int`" would read "`1k`" and report `1024`, **to help consumption by scripts**.

See [commit 5f96742](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f9674243d0341519e5031681c941b0e1ad7a9e3) (18 Nov 2017) by [Haaris Mehmood (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6cddb73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cddb7362ca3c7312b57a4f172bca5c953a45b6c), 06 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### `config`: add `--expiry-date`
>
> Add `--expiry-date` as a data-type for config files when '`git config --get`' is used. This will return any relative or fixed dates from config files as timestamps.
>
> This is useful for scripts (e.g. `gc.reflogexpire`) that work
>   with timestamps **so that '`2.weeks`' can be converted to a format
>   acceptable by those scripts/functions**.
>
> Following the convention of `git_config_pathname()`, move
>   the helper function required for this feature from
>   `builtin/reflog.c` to `builtin/config.c` where other similar
>   functions exist (e.g. for `--bool` or `--path`), and match
>   the order of parameters with other functions (i.e. output
>   pointer as first parameter).

So the [`git config` documentation now reads](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5f9674243d0341519e5031681c941b0e1ad7a9e3/Documentation/git-config.txt#L183-L186):

```
--expiry-date:
```

> `git config` will ensure that the **output is converted from a fixed or relative date-string to a timestamp.**
>   This option has no effect when setting the value.